# Find the degree of the field extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a field. Let $K(X)$ be the field of rational functions of $x$. And let $K(X^n)$ be a subfield. Show that $[K(X):K(X^n)]=n$.

In my understanding, we can treat $K(X)$ as a $K(X^n)$-vector space. So we have the basis $B=\{1, x, \cdots, x^{n-1}\} $ which has $n$ elements. Thus, the degree of of the field extension is $n$.

Now I want to show that $B$ is a basis.
For the linear independence, I'm stuck on the part commented below.

For spanning, I'm a bit confused. Given an element $y$ in $K(x)$, we want to show $y= a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots + a_0$ for $a_i\in K(X^n)$. In this case, is the result clear using mod $x^n$? Or do I still need to show other things?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have to *prove* that this is a basis. It clearly spans, but you also need to verify that it is linearly independent over $K(X^n)$.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960739/degree-field-extension-by-a-power-of-transcendental-element?noredirect=1).

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. For linear independence, suppose $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_j x^j =0 $, isn't it clear that $a_j=0$?

Comment: But the $a_j$ are elements of $K(X^n)$, so each $a_j$ looks like $a_j = \frac{p_j(X^n)}{q_j(X^n)}$, where $p_j$ and $q_j$ are polynomials with coefficients in $K$. So what you "really" have is something like $$\frac{p_0(X^n)}{q_0(X^n)} + \frac{p_1(X^n)}{q_1(X^n)}X + \cdots + \frac{p_{n-1}(X^n)}{q_{n-1}(X^n)}X^{n-1} = 0.$$ Is it "clear" that $p_i(X^n) = 0$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$?

Comment: Note you have things backwards by the way: you have to view $K(X)$ as a vector space over $K(X^n)$, not the other way around. $K(X^n)$ is not a vector space over $K(x)$ if $n\gt 1$, since $xx^n\notin K(X^n)$

Comment: Right..So we want to show that each $p_i(X^n)=0$. And $p_i$ is of the form $p_i(x^n)=a_0 + a_1x^n +a_2x ^{2n} + \cdots$ for $a_i \in K$. And we want to show that $a_i=0$. From here I'm not sure how to proceed. Can we just say that the set $\{ x^n, x^{2n}, \cdots\}$ is linearly independent? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Not that difficult, but you have to do the work. After clearing denominators you have $P_0(X^n) + P_1(X^n)X + \cdots + P_{n-1}(X^n)X^{n-1}$. Every monomial in the first summand has powers of $X$ congruent to $0$ mod $n$, in the second they are congruent to $1$ modulo $n$, etc. So from there you conclude the coefficients of the $P_i$ have to be zero, and therefore that the original $p_i$ had to be zero (since the $q_j$ were nonzero, and each $P_i$ is the product of $p_i$ with some fo the $q_j$).

Comment: Because $x$ satisfies a the polynomial $t^n-x^n\in K(x^n)$, the degree of the extension is at most $n$. Alternatively, every element of $K(x)$ can be written as a polynomial in $x$ with coefficients in $K(x^n)$ (because $x$ is algebraic over $K(x^n)$, so givne $p(t)\in K(x^n)[t]$, write $p(t) = (t^n-x^n)q(t) + r(t)$ with $r=0$ or $\deg(r)\lt n$, and note that $p(x) = r(x)$, so $1,x,\ldots,x^{n-1}$ span.